# Insert Headers and Footers wordpress plugin leads me to 403 error page

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress website and I just want to connect come API and return some data
the problem is that I can't add any script insert headers and footers plugin, cuz every single time I try to add a script I press save I get the 403 error page
even simple scripts like

```
<style>
   *{box-sizing:border-box;}
</style>
```

is not working and still showing the 403 error page

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?more_on=xron.net). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting. You are expected to show any research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this usually cause by a security/firewall plugin or security settings from your server. Firstly, temporary disable any security/firewall plugin on your site, save your changes and reactive the plugin later.

If you don't have any security/firewall plugin installed, then temporary remove any security/firewall settings on your sever, save your changes and reactive later.